# Firebase cannot store custom fields using android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to store a custom field in firebase using firstname of the user. I'm using real-time database in firebase. When I click register, it stores the email and password into the firebase but the first name field doesn't store. I'm new to firebase and I'm pretty sure I've installed the correct dependencies in connecting the app to firebase.

I created a **UserDetails.java** class to create a constructor of my variables and store it to firebase using this:

**UPDATED**

```
package com.test.smartparkingsystem_cit;

public class UserDetails {
    public String firstname, lastname, email, password, phonenumber, vehiclenumber;


    public UserDetails(){

    }

    public UserDetails(String firstname, String lastname, String email, String password, String phonenumber, String vehiclenumber) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
        this.vehiclenumber = vehiclenumber;
    }
}
```

I'm quite sure that I've Initialized the firebase instance and store the data in firebase using this code:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
if(task.isSuccessful()) {
// call the constructor UserDetails.java and store user details to firebase
UserDetails user = new UserDetails(
        email,
        firstname
);

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
       .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
       .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
       progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       if(task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(register.this, getString(R.string.registration_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }else {
           Toast.makeText(register.this, "Could not store to database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
});

}
else {
// Send Error message to application
Toast.makeText(register.this, "Some error occur, please check.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
});
```

But only the email and password is stored in the database, the first name was not included. Could someone help?

Here's the code below in my **Register.java**:

```
package com.test.sample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth; // declare firebase authentication
    private Button back_btn; // create button config to open activity_register
    private Button register_btn; // create button config to register user
    ProgressBar progressBar; // declare progress bar after user registers

    // Declare variables for register
    EditText reg_email, reg_password, reg_fname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        // Write a message to the database
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");


        //Initialize variables according to ID
        reg_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        reg_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        reg_fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_fname);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // Initialize Firebase Instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Register Button
        register_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg_confirmbtnreg); // register User
        register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RegisterUser();
            }
        });
    }



    // Function Register User
    private void RegisterUser() {

        // Initialize variables and get text inputs
         final String email = reg_email.getText().toString().trim();
         final String password = reg_password.getText().toString().trim();
         final String firstname = reg_fname.getText().toString().trim();

        // ** Check Empty Fields Start **//
        // check if email is empty
        if(email.isEmpty()) {
            reg_email.setError("Email is required.");
            reg_email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        // check if password is empty
        if(password.isEmpty()) {
            reg_password.setError("Password is required.");
            reg_password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        // check if first name is empty
        if(firstname.isEmpty()) {
            reg_fname.setError("First Name is required.");
            reg_fname.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        // ** Check Empty Fields End **//

        // check if email is valid
        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
        {
            reg_email.setError("Please enter a valid email.");
            reg_email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        // check if password is minimum
        if(password.length()<5) {
            reg_password.setError("Minimum length of password should be 5.");
            reg_password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        // check if first name is minimum characters
        if(firstname.length()<1) {
            reg_fname.setError("First name should be 3-10 characters.");
            reg_fname.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        // set visible progressbar once user clicks register button
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Function to store data to firebase
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // call the constructor UserDetails.java and store user details to firebase
                    UserDetails user = new UserDetails(
                            email,
                            firstname
                    );

                   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                           .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                           .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                           progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(register.this, getString(R.string.registration_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }else {
                               Toast.makeText(register.this, "Could not store to database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       }
                   });

                }
                else {
                    // Send Error message to application
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "Some error occur, please check.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In my **build.grade** under app. I've installed these dependencies for connecting firebase and real-time database. Is there also a problem with this? Please help. Thanks

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
}
```

Comment: What is the code in UserDetails.java?

Comment: Please add the content of your `UserDetails` class and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: That is the code under UserDetails.java, above the constructor. I added  Public String email, firstname. And that is all.

Comment: @AlexMamo That is the code under UserDetails java

Comment: I see how you construct an object of `UserDetails` but I cannot see content of the class.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've updated the code, under 'UserDetails.java'

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
UserDetails user = new UserDetails(
    email,
    firstname
);
```

to

```
UserDetail suser = new UserDetails(
    firstname,
    lastname,
    email,
    password,
    phonenumber,
    vehiclenumber
);
```

In this way, you are constructing an object of your `UserDetails` class by passing all the values to the constructor. In your code, you are passing only tow values values to a two-argument constructor that does not exist.

Comment: I've tried it sir. But it won't save to database. I've already erased the remaining values and used only the firstname,email, and password for the constructor

Comment: As I see, there is also no constructor with three arguments. Have you tried to create an object in the exact way I have explained in my answer? What's the behaviour?